# Why does PSEXEC -i -s work in Windows 7 as services can no longer interact with the desktop?

Tags: windows-7, windows, psexec, interactive

According to this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Important  Services cannot directly interact with a user as of Windows Vista. Therefore, the techniques mentioned in the section titled Using an Interactive Service should not be used in new code.

Why does `psexec \\REMOTEPCNAME -i -s cmd` still actually work properly and launch a command prompt in the `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` context?  Does SysInternals have Windows cheat codes?

Comment: *Does SysInternals have Windows cheat codes?* - Yes, Its Microsoft Software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The psexec service has sufficient privileges (SeTcbPrivilege) to obtain tokens for other sessions with **[WTSQueryUserToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** (which it then gives to [CreateProcessAsUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429.aspx) or something similar).

See also: http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2007/10/20/how-to-launch-a-process-in-a-terminal-session/